# Unknown column 'member1' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

after searching in google and SO,i decided to put this here..
i tried changing single quote and backtick to column but it didn't help either..
any help appreciated!!!

```
$a=mysql_query("UPDATE exercisemember SET reps='$reps' WHERE memid='$memid1'")       or die(mysql_error());

    $b=mysql_query("UPDATE exercisemember SET sets1='$sets1' WHERE memid='$memid1'")       or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advances..
update 1
the member1 is actually the value of $memid1

Comment: Are you sure you talking about this query ? As I cannot see `member1` anywhere in your query.

Comment: member1 is actually the value of $memid,php variable..

Comment: Don't user mysql_* function anymore : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @billyonecan thanks for ur interest..it seems like the error is comin from other query...

Comment: Please let me know what you get for `desc exercisemember`

Answer (score 0):

As your title says, there is no colimn member1. What the problem could be is that you you have qoute in the $memid.

Please do an echo on $memid to see what is in the variabele.

Also you could better use pdo or mysqli

it will be something like this with pdo:

```
//database connection
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

$sql = 'UPDATE exercisemember SET reps=:reps WHERE memid=:memid';
$update = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$update->bindParam(':reps', $reps, PDO::PARAM_STR); //if it is a integer use PDO::PARAM_INT
$update->bindParam(':memid', $memid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->execute();
```

This will prevent it from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a=mysql_query("UPDATE exercisemember SET reps='".$reps."' WHERE memid='".$memid1."'")
```

you can find difference using `echo` query